# How to locate all columns in all tables that have all NULL values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have legacy SQL Server database that's been upgraded since forever. I shaved the DB down to keep only last 4 years worth of information.

As a result of its longevity, there are a ton of columns that are no longer used and have been deprecated over the years.

I am looking to find a reasonably painless way to locate all columns in all tables that have nothing but NULL values.

Other than writing a little desktop app to do it, is there a way to do this via SQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979866/how-can-i-find-all-columns-that-are-filled-with-100-nulls-in-my-sql-server-data

Answer (score 1):

Yes, select `count()` over every column. Those that return `0` are the ones that only have `null` values.

Like this:

```
 select count(col1) col1 from mytable
```

Repeat for every table and column.

You could generate such SQL statements with this statement:

```
SELECT 'SELECT COUNT(' + COLUMN_NAME + ') AS COLUMN_NAME FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + ';'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```

Take the output of the above query and execute it as batch of SQL SELECT statements, and inspect the result, locating all the 0 outputs.

Comment: Could you give some feed-back on whether this answered your question?