# SQL to find the names of all columns in a table where the SUM of the column is greater than zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, jdbc

I have a table in SQL Sever 2005 where many of the columns contain only NULL or 0 or 0.0.
I want a query to find the names of every column in that table that have a SUM greater than 0 i.e. the table contains at least one row where its value is not null and is greater than zero.

Thanks.

Comment: Which do you want: the names of all the columns, or just an indication of whether or a row exists in which all fields are non-null and > 0? The answers to the two will be different. :)

Comment: @djacobson I want the names of those columns. I want this query to work assuming I don't know the names of the columns in the table. Thanks!

Comment: Can this be a stored procedure or does it have to be an inline query?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest I believe would be to take the output of following statement and run it as a script.

```
SELECT  SELECT COUNT(*), ''' + name + ''' FROM dbo.ATable WHERE ' + name + '> 0'
FROM    sys.columns sc
WHERE   OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'ATable'
```

*I don't know the system tables off hand but you can exclude anything not being a number by looking at the types of the individual columns. If I'm not mistaken, you could join with sys.types*

If you need a generic solution, it would be possible to concot a dynamic statement passed to execsql but it would be overkill for a one time fix.

Comment: I want to run this query regularly via JDBC. So I'm not sure how I could execute this script like that.

Comment: If it's always one table, create a hardcoded stored procedure that mails you the results periodically. I do wonder about your use case. Perhaps if you'd explain that, we could come up with better alternatives.

Comment: @Lieven I have a drop down list that lets the user select which column to use from the table. I want a query to populate the drop down list. 
Since it's possible that new columns were added or removed it is necessary to query to find out what the columns all are. In addition I want to remove all the names of columns that don't have data in them from that list.

Comment: @Adam, I assume you don't have control over when and how the new columns get created?

Comment: @Adam, you might get some inspiration here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only.