# Find columns that contain only zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working with SQL Server 2008. I have a list of column names on a table and I'd like to know how to use SQL to return the names of those columns which contain nothing but zero or NULL values.

Comment: I'm assuming you want an automated way without having to know the names of the columns?

Comment: that would be nice, but I do know the names of the columns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Select columns with NULL values only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only)

Comment: It's intriguing to see which of the answers allow the query optimizer to use indexes to make quick work of the problem.  It may be worth looking at the execution plans to see what goes on under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @T table
(
  Col1 int,
  Col2 int,
  Col3 int,
  Col4 int
)

insert into @T values
(1,   0   , null, null),
(0,   null, 0   , 1)

select U.ColName
from
  (
    select count(nullif(Col1, 0)) as Col1,
           count(nullif(Col2, 0)) as Col2,
           count(nullif(Col3, 0)) as Col3,
           count(nullif(Col4, 0)) as Col4
    from @T
  ) as T
unpivot
  (C for ColName in (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)) as U
where U.C = 0
```

Result:

```
ColName
----------
Col2
Col3
```

The idea behind this is to count the non `null` values and only keep those with a count of `0`.

[COUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) will only count non null values.
[NULLIF(ColX, 0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) will make all `0` into `null`.
The inner query returns one row with four columns. [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) will turn it around so you have two columns and four rows.
Finally `where U.C = 0` makes sure that you only get the columns that has no values other than `null` or `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a brute force way, since you know all the column names.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.splunge
(
    a INT,
    b INT,
    c INT,
    d INT
);

INSERT dbo.splunge VALUES (0,0,1,-1), (0,NULL,0,0), (0,0,0,NULL);


SELECT 
    cols = STUFF(
       CASE WHEN MIN(COALESCE(a,0)) = MAX(COALESCE(a,0)) THEN ',a' ELSE '' END 
     + CASE WHEN MIN(COALESCE(b,0)) = MAX(COALESCE(b,0)) THEN ',b' ELSE '' END
     + CASE WHEN MIN(COALESCE(c,0)) = MAX(COALESCE(c,0)) THEN ',c' ELSE '' END
     + CASE WHEN MIN(COALESCE(d,0)) = MAX(COALESCE(d,0)) THEN ',d' ELSE '' END,
       1, 1, '')
FROM dbo.splunge;

-- result:
-- a,b

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.splunge;
```

You could probably generate much of this script instead of doing it manually, assuming you know the naming scheme or data type of the columns you want (or just by leaving off the where clause entirely and removing the columns you *don't* want manually).

```
SELECT CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' + CASE WHEN MIN(COALESCE(' + name + ',0)) = '
    + 'MAX(COALESCE(' + name + ',0)) THEN '',' + name + ''' ELSE '''' END'
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.splunge')
    -- AND system_type_id = 56
    -- AND name LIKE '%some pattern%'
;
```

The output will look like the middle of the first query, so you can copy & paste and then remove the first `+` and add the surrounding `STUFF` and query...

Comment: What does "failed" mean? Wrong answer? Error message? If an error message, what is it? Are you using SQL Server 2008 as the original poster?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that works for any table:

```
declare @tableName nvarchar(max) = N'myTable'
declare @columnName nvarchar(max)
create table #zeros (column_name varchar(max))

declare c cursor local forward_only read_only for 
    select column_name
    from information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = @tableName

open c

fetch next from c into @columnName

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    declare @retval int
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 
        N'set @retval = (select count(*) from ' + @tableName + N' where coalesce(' + @columnName + N', 0) <> 0)'

    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@retval int out', @retval=@retval out

    select @retval

    if @retval = 0
    begin
        insert into #zeros (column_name) values (@columnName)
    end 

    fetch next from c into @columnName
end

close c
deallocate c

select * from #zeros

drop table #zeros
```