# Return columns which has NULL or 0 Values in a row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null

I've a `Table` with 10 fields. Each `field` or `column` contains `Integer` values.

Now I need only field(s) to be returned which has `Null` or `0` in the result set.

Comment: only fields or only rows with all fields non-null and != 0 ?

Comment: It's not the same (this is for SQL-Server), but It will help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only/63868#63868

Comment: @ElVieejo the link you posted is for finding records where ALL selected columns are null... the OP wants records which have a 0 or null in them

Comment: It's a little difference. It will give him an Idea. He wants show columns where, at least one row has this column value with null or 0

Comment: Hello spencer7593, Your given examples will not help me in this scenario as because there is some confusion understanding the actual problem. Let me be more specific. Lets consider i have a table mytable with 5 columns (excluding primary key) from cols1 to cols5. Now each column will hold its integer values. e.g. Cols1 = 697, cols2=523, cols3=123, cols4=0, cols5=0 where user_id=x (x is a primary key. I need records of that user x only, since there is only 1 row for each user). I need a query which will only show cols4=0 & cols5=0 in the result set for user x. Other 3 columns wont be displayed.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me. For instance:

Instead of:

```
where column_name is null or column_name = 0
```

It would be:

```
where COALESCE(column_name,0) = 0
```

[Posted by Jon Gabrielson on December 18, 2002](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)

> The function 'COALESCE' can simplify working with null values. for
>   example, to treat null as zero, you can use: select
>   COALESCE(colname,0) from table where COALESCE(colname,0) > 1;

Comment: The same effect can be achieved with:
```where ifnull(column_name, 0) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `where column_name is null or column_name = 0`

Comment: The problem with this method is that your code will be broken once you add or remove any columns from that table.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you are asking.

Can you elaborate a bit on what the resultset should look like, do you want all 10 columns returned, but only include the rows that have at least one column containing NULL or 0? That's very easy to do, by specifying appropriate predicates in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9
  FROM mytable
 WHERE IFNULL(col0,0) = 0
    OR IFNULL(col1,0) = 0
    OR IFNULL(col2,0) = 0
    OR IFNULL(col3,0) = 0
    OR IFNULL(col4,0) = 0
    OR IFNULL(col5,0) = 0
    OR IFNULL(col6,0) = 0
    OR IFNULL(col7,0) = 0
    OR IFNULL(col8,0) = 0
    OR IFNULL(col9,0) = 0
```

That will return all rows that have a zero or NULL in at least one of the specified columns.

But your question seems to be asking about something a little bit different; you seem to be asking about returning only certain columns based on conditions.  The columns to be returned in the result set are determined by the list of expressions following the `SELECT` keyword.  You can't dynamically alter the expressions in the SELECT list based on the values the column contain.

To return the names of the columns which have at least one row that contains a NULL or zero in that column, you could write a query like this (this is limited to 5 columns, could be easily extended to 10 or more columns):

```
SELECT 'col0' AS col_name FROM mytable WHERE IFNULL(col0,0) = 0
 UNION SELECT 'col1' FROM mytable WHERE IFNULL(col1,0) = 0
 UNION SELECT 'col2' FROM mytable WHERE IFNULL(col2,0) = 0
 UNION SELECT 'col3' FROM mytable WHERE IFNULL(col3,0) = 0
 UNION SELECT 'col4' FROM mytable WHERE IFNULL(col4,0) = 0
```

(That query is going to do some serious scanning through the table. If indexes are available, the predicates can be rewritten to allow for index range scan.)

Here's a way to to the column_names in a single row. (A NULL in one of the columns would mean that the column does not contain any zeros or NULL.)

```
SELECT (SELECT 'col0' FROM mytable WHERE IFNULL(col0,0)=0 LIMIT 1) AS col0
     , (SELECT 'col1' FROM mytable WHERE IFNULL(col1,0)=0 LIMIT 1) AS col1
     , (SELECT 'col2' FROM mytable WHERE IFNULL(col2,0)=0 LIMIT 1) AS col2
     , (SELECT 'col3' FROM mytable WHERE IFNULL(col3,0)=0 LIMIT 1) AS col3
     , (SELECT 'col4' FROM mytable WHERE IFNULL(col4,0)=0 LIMIT 1) AS col4
```

But it would be much faster to do a single scan through the table:

```
SELECT IF(c0>0,'col0',NULL)
     , IF(c1>0,'col1',NULL)
     , IF(c2>0,'col2',NULL)
     , IF(c3>0,'col3',NULL)
     , IF(c4>0,'col4',NULL)
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(IF(IFNULL(col0,0)=0,1,0)) AS c0
              , SUM(IF(IFNULL(col1,0)=0,1,0)) AS c1 
              , SUM(IF(IFNULL(col2,0)=0,1,0)) AS c2 
              , SUM(IF(IFNULL(col3,0)=0,1,0)) AS c3
              , SUM(IF(IFNULL(col3,0)=0,1,0)) AS c4
         FROM mytable 
       )
```

Comment: He wants to show only columns where, at least, one of it's values of one of the rows is null. the problem from your code is that you are showing all columns

Comment: Hello spencer7593, Your given examples will not help me in this scenario as because there is some confusion understanding the actual problem. Let me be more specific. Lets consider i have a table mytable with 5 columns (excluding primary key) from cols1 to cols5. Now each column will hold its integer values. e.g. Cols1 = 697, cols2=523, cols3=123, cols4=0, cols5=0 where user_id=x (x is a primary key. I need records of that user x only, since there is only 1 row for each user). I need a query which will only show cols4=0 & cols5=0 in the result set for user x. Other 3 columns wont be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to make a similar method in another language. The logic was to check that all "columns" in a record were "true" before it could be processed.

The way I got around it was with this logic:

```
# loop through the records
for ($i=0; $i<count($records); $i++) {

  # in each record, if any column is 0 or null we will disgard it
  # this boolean will tell us if we can keep the record or not
  # default value is 'true', this gives it a chance to survive
  $keepit = true;

  # loop through each column
  for ($j=0; $j<count($records[$i]); $j++) {

    # add your boolean condition (true=go ahead, false=cant go ahead)
    $goahead = (!is_null($records[$i][$j]) && $records[$i][$j] != 0);

    # convert the boolean to a 0 or 1,
    # find the minimum number in a record
    # (so if any field in a record is false i.e. 0 or null, dont use the record)
    $keepit = min(+$goahead, +$keepit);

  }#end of col loop

  if ($keepit) {
    # keep the record
    array_push($anotherArray, $records[$i]);
  }

}
```

I've written this in PHP for you. It's probably doable in MySQL too but I'd recommend you fetch all of the records, process them in PHP, and send them back to MySQL.

In future, you should design your database table so that invalid records are not allowed/not stored in the first place.

Comment: Hello, Your given examples will not help me in this scenario as because there is some confusion understanding the actual problem. Let me be more specific. Lets consider i have a table mytable with 5 columns (excluding primary key) from cols1 to cols5. Now each column will hold its integer values. e.g. Cols1 = 697, cols2=523, cols3=123, cols4=0, cols5=0 where user_id=x (x is a primary key. I need records of that user x only, since there is only 1 row for each user). I need a query which will only show cols4=0 & cols5=0 in the result set for user x. Other 3 columns wont be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the *columns* that have NULL or 0, or the *rows* with a column that is NULL or 0, or the rows where *all* columns are either NULL or 0?

But I doubt you would have 10 equivalent columns in a well-designed table, so you might want to re-design your data model -- make the columns rows in another table, and join the two tables together.

You might have something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE a(a_id int primary key, b0 int, b1 int, b2 int, ..., b9 int );
```

But you want this:

```
CREATE TABLE a( a_id int primary key );
CREATE TABLE b( b_id int primary key );

INSERT INTO b (b_id) values (0), (1), ..., (9);

CREATE TABLE ab (
  a_id int, b_id int,
  v int not null, -- this would be the value of b0, b1, ...
  foreign key (a_id) references a(a_id),
  foreign key (b_id) references b(b_id),
  primary key(a_id, b_id)
);
```

And then you can write something like:

```
SELECT * FROM a, b -- cross join to get all possible combinations
WHERE (a_id, b_id) NOT IN (
  -- then remove the ones that have a value
  SELECT a_id, b_id FROM a JOIN ab ON a.id = ab.a_id JOIN b ON ab.a_id
  WHERE ab.v <> 0);
```

The last line is unnecessary if, before running it, you delete all 0'd lines:

```
DELETE FROM ab WHERE v = 0;
```

Comment: Hello, There is some confusion understanding the actual problem. Let me be more specific. Lets consider i have a table mytable with 5 columns (excluding primary key) from cols1 to cols5. Now each column will hold its integer values. e.g. Cols1 = 697, cols2=523, cols3=123, cols4=0, cols5=0 where user_id=x (x is a primary key. I need records of that user x only, since there is only 1 row for each user). I need a query which will only show cols4=0 & cols5=0 in the result set for user x. Other 3 columns wont be displayed.