# Find out all the columns having Null values in the table in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, null

I am using Sql Server 2008. In one of my table's columns having null values. Now I want to find out all the columns that have null value in the table using query.

So how to find out all the columns which have null values in the table in SQL?

Comment: Take a peek at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your table is

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
A INT PRIMARY KEY,
B CHAR(1000) NULL,
C CHAR(1000) NULL
)
```

One way would be

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN B IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B,
    MAX(CASE WHEN C IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C
FROM T
```

This is simple but potentially could end up scanning the whole table unnecessarily. Even if the first row scanned contains `NULL` for both columns.

A query that potentially avoids that is

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 NullExists
FROM test T 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN 'b' END),
                   (CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN 'c' END)) V(NullExists)
WHERE NullExists IS NOT NULL
```

Execution plans and some alternative approaches are in [my question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19344/how-to-efficiently-check-exists-on-multiple-columns).

Comment: thanks @Martin Smith. that's i want.