# Finding database columns that are not touched by CRUD stored procs

Tags: c#, sql

I work on a development team that maintains a (large) legacy C# app.  We have come across several instances in the past few months where columns in the database do not have any reference in the CRUD stored procs that select/update/insert/delete from that table, so they are in effect "orphan" columns" and their values are always NULL (clearly they are not business critical or someone would have complained by now, but we would like to know where these orphan columns are since we are working on a total platform migration).

For example, Table "Product" has the following columns:

ProductID
ProductName
ProductDesc
EffectiveDate
EndDate
IsEnabled

The Product_INSERT stored procedure inserts data for the following columns:

ProductID
ProductName
ProductDesc
EffectiveDate
EndDate

As you can see, IsEnabled is not included in the stored proc, so it will get inserted as NULL (assuming the column is nullable, otherwise we would have faced an error upon insert and realized the discrepancy).

Is there any way to run a SQL query to identify these?  We have numerous screens that have a lot of underlying CRUD sprocs.

Comment: you want to identify the names of columns which contained exclusively `NULL` values, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.[columns] AS c
INNER JOIN sys.[tables] AS t ON [c].[object_id] = [t].[object_id]
WHERE 1=1
--AND c.[object_id] = 60579304
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT TOP(1) 1
FROM dbo.sysobjects so
INNER JOIN dbo.syscomments sc ON so.id = sc.id 
WHERE 
    (so.xtype = 'P')
    and OBJECTPROPERTY(so.id, N'IsMSShipped')=0 
    AND sc.[text] LIKE '%' + c.[name] + '%'
)
```

Not to elegant but works. Finds columns not used in `Stored Procs`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to know a list of tables/columns which do not contain any non-NULL values.

You can use a cursor and systables to accomplish this. Iterate over all tables, then iterate over all their columns to see if they are all `NULL`

This will also return completely empty tables, but you can fix that if you want by adding another `EXISTS` clause to see that there are records.

```
declare @tab varchar(255)

declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)

DECLARE gettab cursor for
SELECT t.name FROM sys.tables t
OPEN gettab

FETCH NEXT FROM gettab into @tab

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
WHERE t.Name = @tab
OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @cmd = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT top 1 * FROM ' + @tab + ' WHERE [' + @col + '] IS NOT NULL) BEGIN print ''' + @tab + '.' + @col + ''' end'
    EXEC(@cmd)

    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
END

CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM gettab into @tab
END
CLOSE gettab
DEALLOCATE gettab
```

Slightly modified from the answer here:

[SQL: Select columns with NULL values only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only)