# How can I find all columns that have only NULL values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a quick and easy way to identify all of the columns with all NULL values in my table?  I have a table with the maximum limit of columns and since I want to add additional columns, I have to first delete some of the existing non-used columns.  How can I do this?

Comment: You have a table with more than 1024 columns?

Comment: It has exactly 1024 columns now and I need to add more columns.  This is not my preference to have so many columns in one table but it is needed to support existing software.

Comment: Please. Tell me why you have 1024 column.

Comment: http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2009/02/15/script-find-all-empty-columns-in-database/

Comment: I must have 1024 columns to support our software; I didn't design this table or the software.  This is the way it has to be.

Comment: @salvationishere -- 1024 columns might be the way it is right now, but it is certainly not "the way it has to be."

Comment: Please try my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16550333/2370941

Comment: Awesome, syneptody!  That did it!  Thanks!