# SQL - Can't check if NULL

Tags: sql, select, join

If I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN friendship ON users.username = friendship.user_name
```

I get the following result

[image]

But if I add the following WHERE at the end, I don't get any results at all!

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN friendship ON users.username = friendship.user_name WHERE friendship.friend_name = NULL
```

Does somebody know what's the problem here? (I haven't used JOIN in a while, you must know)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Select columns with NULL values only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`. `IS` is the correct comparer with a null value.

Comment: Works great, thank you for the INCREDIBLY fast answer.
I'll set is as an answer as soon as I'm allowed to

Answer (score 8):

```
WHERE friendship.friend_name = NULL
```

You can't compare to NULL using `=`, you'll need to use `IS NULL`;

```
WHERE friendship.friend_name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that :

```
... WHERE friendship.friend_name IS NULL
```

**Instead of :**

```
WHERE friendship.friend_name = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

dship ON users.username = friendship.user_name WHERE friendship.friend_name=''

Use this

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN friendship ON users.username = friendship.user_name AND friendship.friend_name = NULL
```

The where clause is filtering away rows where the left join doesn't succeed. Move it to the join: