# how we can delete column when All data IS Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a problem in SQL Sever 2008 R2...
I Have a Pivot Table and rows is Dynamic created 
for example when execute in

Line 1

ID  ,  Modify_Date , Line_Code , T1 , T2 , T6 , T9 , T22 , T11

---

Line 2
ID  ,  Modify_Date , Line_Code , T4 , T2 , T5 , T3

---

and so have a different Results when execution and some fields in columns IS NULL and no have data for all rows

[image]
I want to delete Column "T9"
Thanks

Comment: if not exists (select * from table where T9 is not null)  ???

Comment: Maybe there is more to your question? To get rid of a column in a table use ALTER TABLE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can refer this [SQL: Select columns with NULL values only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only)
and rewrite the @cmd as below：

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE
 @ColumnName sysname
,@DataType nvarchar(128)
,@cmd nvarchar(max)
,@TableSchema nvarchar(128) = 'dbo'
,@TableName sysname = 'TableName';--Your Table Name

DECLARE getinfo CURSOR FOR
SELECT
     c.COLUMN_NAME
    ,c.DATA_TYPE
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
WHERE
    c.TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema
    AND c.TABLE_NAME = @TableName;

OPEN getinfo;

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo INTO @ColumnName, @DataType;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @TableSchema + N'.' + @TableName 
             + N' WHERE [' + @ColumnName + N'] IS NOT NULL) '
             + N' ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + N' DROP COLUMN ' + @ColumnName + N';';
    EXECUTE (@cmd);
    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo INTO @ColumnName, @DataType;
END;

CLOSE getinfo;
DEALLOCATE getinfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this optimized code

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ColumnName  SYSNAME,
        @DataType    NVARCHAR(128),
        @cmd         NVARCHAR(max),
        @TableSchema NVARCHAR(128) = 'dbo',
        @TableName   SYSNAME = 'TEST'; --Your Table Name
DECLARE getinfo CURSOR FOR
  SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME,
         c.DATA_TYPE
  FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
  WHERE  c.TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema
         AND c.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
         AND C.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'

OPEN getinfo;

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo INTO @ColumnName, @DataType;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      SET @cmd = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM '
                 + @TableSchema + N'.' + @TableName + N' WHERE ['
                 + @ColumnName + N'] IS NOT NULL) '
                 + N' ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName
                 + N' DROP COLUMN ' + @ColumnName + N';';

      EXECUTE (@cmd);

      FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo INTO @ColumnName, @DataType;
  END;

CLOSE getinfo;

DEALLOCATE getinfo;
```

Comment: This is similar to Angus Chung Answer but added one more filter condition (Is_nullable='YES')