# SQL: Select columns WITHOUT NULL values only in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This question is the exact opposite of [SQL: Select columns with NULL values only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only).

Given a table with 1024 columns, how to find all columns WITHOUT null values?

Input:`a table with 1024 columns`

Output:`col1_name(no null values) col2_name(no null values)...`

Comment: well, a nonwide table can have a maximum of 1,024 columns, and a wide table can have up to 30,000

Comment: did you read the first two comments on that answer?

Comment: @scsimon I did. If you replace it, ` you'll get a list of columns that have at least 1 record with a value`

Comment: Write a query with as many `count` expressions as you have columns and see which are `0`.

Comment: What you want for 'output' is a bit ambiguous. Are you just wanting the names of all the columns that have no nulls in them in any row in the table? I provided that solution, but upon re-reading, I'm not sure if that's exactly what you were asking for.

Comment: @pmbAustin Yes. Upvoted and accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid using a CURSOR, this method will simply list out the column names of any columns that have no NULL values in them anywhere in the table... just set the @TableName at the top:

```
DECLARE @tableName sysname;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = N'';
SET @tableName = N'Reports_table';

SELECT @sql += 'SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE '+ COLUMN_NAME + ' IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE ''' + COLUMN_NAME +
''' END AS ColumnsWithNoNulls UNION ALL '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName
SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, LEN(@sql) - 10);
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results;
CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnsWithNoNulls sysname NULL);
INSERT INTO #Results EXEC(@sql);
SELECT * FROM #Results WHERE ColumnsWithNoNulls IS NOT NULL
```

As a bonus, the results are in a temp table, #Results, so you can query to get any information you want... counts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i modified the [Select columns with NULL values only.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only)

to work for your case :

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 

declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)

DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
WHERE t.Name = 'Reports_table'

OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @cmd = 'IF (SELECT sum(iif([' + @col + '] is null,1,null)) FROM Reports_table) is null  BEGIN print ''' + @col + ''' end'
    exec(@cmd)

    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
END

CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo

SET ANSI_WARNINGS on
```