# Return Columns with only NULL Value

Tags: sql-server

How can I get all columns (in the DB) having only NULL Value.?

If there are 2 tables:
T1

```
A        B

1       NULL
2       NULL
NULL    NULL
```

And T2

```
C        D

NULL    920
NULL    NULL
NULL    2323
```

I want to return B and C

Comment: Doesn't make sense... do you mean B and **C**? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Select columns with NULL values only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only)

Comment: why do you want D to be returend ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean B and C?

Try:

```
Declare @schemaname varchar(255), @tablename varchar(255)

DECLARE table_cur cursor for
SELECT s.name,t.name
FROM sys.tables t Join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id=s.schema_id

OPEN table_cur
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cur into @schemaname, @tablename
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    Declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)

    DECLARE column_cur cursor for
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tablename

    OPEN column_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM column_cur into @col

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @cmd = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT top 1 * FROM ' + @schemaname + '.' + @tablename +' WHERE [' + @col + '] IS NOT NULL) BEGIN print '' Table: ' + @tablename + ', Column: ' + @col + ''' end'
        EXEC(@cmd)

        FETCH NEXT FROM column_cur into @col
    END

    CLOSE column_cur
    DEALLOCATE column_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cur into @schemaname, @tablename

END


CLOSE table_cur
DEALLOCATE table_cur
```