# List of columns with all nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to import a number of text files into SQL Server tables, and some of the text files have columns where all the rows appear to be mostly, if not all, null values.

Is there any simple way to write a query that will list all the columns in a table that have nothing but null values?

Comment: You would have to use dynamic sql for this because you need to query each column. The other option would be to write out each column. I am guessing the intention is to skip columns if all rows are NULL?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "simple".

Comment: This is probably what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only

Comment: Exactly right, Sean

Comment: Very cool, danish, that looks like it will work, thanks!