# Drop empty column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to remove all the empty  column for a given table.
As it could by any table, I do not know the name of the columns.

For example, the input table is table1 :

| Id | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cell 2 | NULL | Cell 2 | NULL |
| 2 | Cell 4 | NULL | Cell 4 | NULL |

The output table should be :

| Id | Value1 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 |
| 2 | Cell 4 | Cell 4 |

Comment: What's wrong with`ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DROP COLUMN Value2, Value4;`?

Comment: Referring to objects dynamically inside of a SQL statement is not something that is allowed in plain-jane SQL. An object is a table, view, procedure, column, etc. In this case you will need to write a query to determine which columns of an inputted table have only NULLs and then once you determine that, write the SQL to ALTER the table to remove the columns. You will have to write this in a script like a Stored Procedure or some outside language like Python or Java or C# or what-have-you, or do it manually. It's no small feat.

Comment: You would either have to use dynamic SQL for this, or maybe handle it in your presentation layer.

Comment: As a starting point for this, check out [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/select-columns-with-null-values-only).

Comment: It is not clear what you are after: (1) `SELECT ...` columns with NOT NULL values, or (2) Change structure of a table `ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can try that.

```
set @sql = null;

select concat_ws(', ',
    case when count(nullif(ID, ''))       > 0 then 'ID'       end,
    case when count(nullif(Value1, '')) > 0 then 'Value1' end,
    case when count(nullif(Value2, ''))    > 0 then 'Value2'    end,
    case when count(nullif(Value3, ''))         > 0 then 'Value3'         end,
    case when count(nullif(Value4, ''))    > 0 then 'Value4'    end
) into @sql
from table1 ;

set @sql = concat('select ', @sql, ' from imported_data where',
                 (
                    SELECT INSERT( GROUP_CONCAT('OR `', `COLUMN_NAME`, '`  != \'\' ' SEPARATOR ' '), 1, 3, '')
                    FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
                    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'mydb'
                        AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'table1'
                )
);  
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

The nullif clause checks if there are any strictly empty fields, if you want to include null values you will have to remove the nullif.